# what is the responsibility of the container component in react+redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new to react redux, it has a concept of "Container Component", which is the same as the "Container Component" in react, which focus on how things work. In redux, the container component used to access state from store, to avoid passing props down to the too many nested child components .

Below are my questions:

(1) Do container components responsible for orginazing the business logic?

(2) There are many posts, like [Where do I put my business logic in a React-Redux application?](https://medium.com/@jeffbski/where-do-i-put-my-business-logic-in-a-react-redux-application-9253ef91ce1), it mentioned to put logic to reducor/action creator/thunk and so on, but not talk about container component, do I miss out something essential?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) No, business logic should be kept in middle-ware, reducers and selectors.

2) Container component is really every component created by connect HOC (everything connected with the store). As said in point 1 it is not a place for business logic.

---

**Bigger answer related to Redux architecture**

When using Redux the convention of `container->presentation` components is not really needed. You should focus on direct connecting components with the store. So instead of choosing which components are connected, are containers, and which are not, are presentation ones, you should focus on delivering the needed data directly.

Preferred is to avoid passing props from parent components and use it when no other way is possible. An example of such avoiding passing props is `List -> Element` components relation. In the approach with container component, the store would be connected to the `List`(container) and `List` would pass all the data to every `Element`(presentation) component. In the approach without `container->presentation`, you would send to the `Element` component only id, and `Element` component would connect to the store, in order to take obligated properties. Therefor sending props is here reduced to the minimum, and because both components are connected to the store, you can not distinguish them on `container->presentation`.

---

**Additional notice about non-redux architecture**

If application doesn't have state management tool like redux, then using `container->presentation` component approach is very reasonable. This is because the business logic stays only in a part of the program, and exactly I mean containers components, and presentation components can be pure and stateless. Thanks `container->presentation` segmentation an application has clear separation between state modification and state purity.

Comment: Thanks Maciej, it sounds make sense.  With redux, it avoid passing props down to presentational component, the HOC container, theoretically returned by the connect somehow like the container without redux, why don't put logic to the mapDispatchToProps to make the container more high cohesion? it seems that the container in redux just used to connect to store, right?

Comment: @RonSmith you put the logic in reducers which will consume your actions dispatched. You use selectors in mapStateToProps and there also you can put some store selecting logic. Async logic you put in middleware like saga. The component itself should have only view logic but not business logic. And you should not have cohesion between component and the store, the component should be not aware the store and that its props are passed by redux, component dosent't know who gives the props. This  gives possibility to have functional components almost all the time.

Comment: I just think the reducer should be simple to return state to update the state, it should not do many complex things within it, also there are some edge cases that it maybe should access some property declared in other reducer. It also become imposible in the reducor.  what if dispatch other actions to other reducer? I think business in logic will face many more issues.

Comment: It is not like the reducer needs to be simple, but in most of the cases it is simple, because you should have decoupled state on many reducers to cover small pieces of it. Reducer doesn't need to check properties of other reducers because it has access to the part of the store which you give to it. Also one action can be consumed by many reducers, communication between them is not possible and is against flux. Reducer doesn't dispatch action but middle-ware does it, in middleware you can run many actions in one time. So yes there exists edge cases bur all are doable in such approach

Comment: Actually, the reducer just solely focus on the state logic, right? according to the action parameter to do something to change state. but such as validation and asyn request we should put it into action creator or middleware?

Comment: yes exactly, async staff and side effects should stay in middle-ware. So for example you dispatch action SAVE from component -> it goes to middle-ware, middle-ware is doing validation, if validation fails it dispatches action VALIDATION_FAILED, if is ok then it does the request, after request dispatches action - SUCCESS.

Comment: @RonSmith where is my +1 :D ?

Comment: thanks a lot. You said middle-ware here is mean we add code to action creator,but the code execute in redux middle ware like thunk and saga right? Such as add logic to function returned in action creator which be called in thunk?

Answer (score 1):

As a general practise

The `container` component specifies the data a `presentational` component should render. The container component also specifies behavior. If the presentational component has any interactivity — like a button — it calls a prop-function given to it by the `container` component. The `container` component is the one to dispatch an action to the `Redux store`. The container component also access the data from the Redux store

A `presentational` component is a component that just renders HTML. The component's only function is presentational markup. In a Redux-powered app, a presentational component does not interact with the Redux store.

Here are some important points that @DanAbramov had mentioned in **[this](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)** article about Container Component

> 1. Are concerned with how things work.
> 2. May contain both presentational and container components** inside but usually don’t have any DOM markup of their own except for some
>      wrapping divs, and never have any styles.
> 3. Provide the data and behavior to presentational or other container components.
> 4. Call Flux actions and provide these as callbacks to the presentational components.
> 5. Are often stateful, as they tend to serve as data sources.
> 6. Are usually generated using higher order components such as connect() from React Redux, createContainer() from Relay, or
>      Container.create() from Flux Utils, rather than written by hand.

Comment: thanks a lot.  as you said, the container component just post down data props and callback function to presentational components, and in callback it will communicate with store. so we should not do the business logic like validation and so on in the container, and instead to put it in action creator?

Comment: The validation should be a part of the container, and container is the one that contains all your logic, action creators should only be used when you want to update data in the store or for API request

Comment: I agree with you, but because we create container with mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps, we cannot access state in mapDispatchToProps function, so sometimes I must put logic to action creator so as to access state easily. This will makes the logic mess, do you have any suggestions for this case?

Comment: Why do you want to access state into mapDispatchToProps function, the action creator will be something that you will call from the container component and that will have access to store through mapStateToProps

Comment: Assume that after click a button in the presentation component,  I want  to do some calculate which should access some data from state, and then dispatch an action to change the state, like this, the logic can be in container. I don't know what is the right way to solve this case. currently I pass a callback to action creator and pass the state back to container. do you have better solution for this?

Comment: The container would pass down a function as props to the presentation component, which would be called by it, in the function you would do all the calculation and then dispatch the action from it and the container gets the state through mapStateToProps

Comment: I don't understand, the callback function do all the calculation,but it shouldn't access state and to dispatch action to update state, then do continue logic after state changed? can you write some code about this?